# Android email friendly keyboard in the input field of webview

Tags: android, email, input, keyboard, webview

I have a webview in which user has to type their email and password in the corresponding input fields. I want to show the email friendly keyboard when the user taps on the email field. How to do it using javascript ?

I tried using the javascript by using the following code

```
 String emailKeyboard="document.getElementById('src').type=\"email\";";
 mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " + emailKeyboard +"})()");
```

also i tried by getting the element by name as

```
String emailKeyboard="document.getElementByName('j_username').type=\"email\";";
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " + emailKeyboard +"})()");
```

where j_username is the name of the input field. But it is not working. Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Senthil.M

Answer (score 1):

Why not just set the type of the fields directly in the HTML rather than trying to add them on the fly (which causes more strain on performance anyway...).